# Custom Post Type Pagination getting 404 error

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

```
function viewevnts() { 
    ob_start();     
$query = ( get_query_var( 'query' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'query' ) : 1;
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'category_name' => 'en-events',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'query' => $query
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
     // CPT content

endwhile;

     $big = 999999999;
     echo paginate_links( array(
          'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
          'format' => '?query=%#%',
          'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('query') ),
          'total' => $loop->max_num_pages,
          'prev_text' => '«',
          'next_text' => '»'
     ) );
     return  $data; 

}

add_shortcode('AllEvents','viewevnts'); // end
```

i tried with above code items displaying but when i click on 2 page it will coming 404 error page.
please help me on this.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a shortcode and not just the standard post type archive template?

Comment: yes @JacobPeattie i'm using shortcode but all items are displaying as above code except the pagination is not working,
i tired without shortcode & coming all data but when i click pagination `<a>` tag pagination it is coming same 404 error.

Comment: @JacobPeattie can you help me on this?

Comment: finally i cracked with
http://flaviusmatis.github.com/simplePagination.js